# How to take a snapshot with Ozeski SDK USB Camera?

Tags: c#, camera, usb, snapshot, ozeki

I'm quite newbie in programming, but triyng to run my first app in VS2019, C# .NET. I want to take a snapshop from my USB microscope. I've found OZEKI SDK library and I'm able to connect and view image from microscope. Ozeki has a tutorial on youtube:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xjMAfMAix9c

and their website,

https://www.camera-sdk.com/p_6553-how-to-take-a-picture-snapshot-and-save-it-as-.jpg-in-c-.html

but when I tried to run app, I got message:
" images.save(curentpath)"  object does not contain a definition  for 'save' and no accesible...."

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Ozeki.Media;
using Ozeki.Camera;

namespace WindowsFormsApp3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
        
        private DrawingImageProvider _imageProvider;
        private MediaConnector _connector;
        private VideoViewerWF _videoViewerWf;
        private SnapshotHandler _snapshotHandler;
        private IWebCamera _webCamera;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _imageProvider = new DrawingImageProvider();
            _connector = new MediaConnector();
            _snapshotHandler = new SnapshotHandler();
            _videoViewerWf = new VideoViewerWF();
            SetVideoViewer();
        }

        private void SetVideoViewer()
        {
            CameraBox.Controls.Add(_videoViewerWf);
            _videoViewerWf.Size = new Size(260, 180);
            _videoViewerWf.BackColor = Color.Black;
            _videoViewerWf.TabStop = false;
            _videoViewerWf.Location = new Point(14, 19);
            _videoViewerWf.Name = "_videoViewerWf";
        }

        private void button_Connect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _webCamera = new WebCamera();

            if (_webCamera != null)
            {
                _connector.Connect(_webCamera.VideoChannel, _imageProvider);
               _connector.Connect(_webCamera.VideoChannel,_snapshotHandler);
                _videoViewerWf.SetImageProvider(_imageProvider);

                _webCamera.Start();
                _videoViewerWf.Start();
            }
        }

    private void button_SaveTo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var result = folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
            if (result == DialogResult.OK)
                TextBox_SaveTo.Text = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
        }

        private void Btn_Snapshot_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var path = TextBox_SaveTo.Text;
            CreateSnapShot(path);
        }

        private void CreateSnapShot(string path)
        {
            var date = DateTime.Now.Year + "y-" + DateTime.Now.Month + "m-" + DateTime.Now.Day + "d-" +
                       DateTime.Now.Hour + "h-" + DateTime.Now.Minute + "m-" + DateTime.Now.Second + "s";
            string currentpath;
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
                currentpath = date + ".jpg";
            else
                currentpath = path + "\\" + date + ".jpg";

            var snapShotImage = _snapshotHandler.TakeSnapshot().ToImage();
            snapShotImage.Save(currentpath, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        }
    }
}
```

and Designer:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp3
{
    partial class Form1
    {
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.folderBrowserDialog1 = new System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog();
            this.groupBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox();
            this.button_Connect = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.CameraBox = new System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox();
            this.groupBox2 = new System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox();
            this.TextBox_SaveTo = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.Btn_Snapshot = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.button_SaveTo1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.groupBox1.SuspendLayout();
            this.groupBox2.SuspendLayout();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // groupBox1
            // 
            this.groupBox1.Controls.Add(this.button_Connect);
            this.groupBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(10, 10);
            this.groupBox1.Name = "groupBox1";
            this.groupBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(120, 60);
            this.groupBox1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.groupBox1.TabStop = false;
            this.groupBox1.Text = "Connect";
            // 
            // button_Connect
            // 
            this.button_Connect.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.5F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(238)));
            this.button_Connect.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
            this.button_Connect.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(10, 20);
            this.button_Connect.Name = "button_Connect";
            this.button_Connect.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 25);
            this.button_Connect.TabIndex = 6;
            this.button_Connect.Text = "Connect";
            this.button_Connect.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.button_Connect.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button_Connect_Click);
            // 
            // CameraBox
            // 
            this.CameraBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(10, 80);
            this.CameraBox.Name = "CameraBox";
            this.CameraBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(285, 210);
            this.CameraBox.TabIndex = 3;
            this.CameraBox.TabStop = false;
            this.CameraBox.Text = "Live camera ";
            // 
            // groupBox2
            // 
            this.groupBox2.Controls.Add(this.TextBox_SaveTo);
            this.groupBox2.Controls.Add(this.Btn_Snapshot);
            this.groupBox2.Controls.Add(this.button_SaveTo1);
            this.groupBox2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(10, 300);
            this.groupBox2.Name = "groupBox2";
            this.groupBox2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(285, 100);
            this.groupBox2.TabIndex = 37;
            this.groupBox2.TabStop = false;
            this.groupBox2.Text = "Snapshot";
            // 
            // TextBox_SaveTo
            // 
            this.TextBox_SaveTo.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(119, 63);
            this.TextBox_SaveTo.Name = "TextBox_SaveTo";
            this.TextBox_SaveTo.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(160, 20);
            this.TextBox_SaveTo.TabIndex = 35;
            this.TextBox_SaveTo.Text = "C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2012\\Projects\\03_Onvif_Network_Video_Record" +
                "er\\03_Onvif_Network_Video_Recorder\\bin\\Debug";
            // 
            // Btn_Snapshot
            // 
            this.Btn_Snapshot.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(10, 20);
            this.Btn_Snapshot.Name = "Btn_Snapshot";
            this.Btn_Snapshot.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 25);
            this.Btn_Snapshot.TabIndex = 36;
            this.Btn_Snapshot.Text = "Take a snapshot";
            this.Btn_Snapshot.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.Btn_Snapshot.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.Btn_Snapshot_Click);
            // 
            // button_SaveTo1
            // 
            this.button_SaveTo1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(10, 60);
            this.button_SaveTo1.Name = "button_SaveTo1";
            this.button_SaveTo1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 25);
            this.button_SaveTo1.TabIndex = 34;
            this.button_SaveTo1.Text = "Save to:";
            this.button_SaveTo1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.button_SaveTo1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button_SaveTo_Click);
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(309, 414);
            this.Controls.Add(this.groupBox2);
            this.Controls.Add(this.CameraBox);
            this.Controls.Add(this.groupBox1);
            this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;
            this.MaximizeBox = false;
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
            this.Text = "Network Video Recorder Snapshot";
            this.groupBox1.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.groupBox2.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.groupBox2.PerformLayout();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
        }

        private System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox groupBox1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button_Connect;
        private System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox CameraBox;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox TextBox_SaveTo;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button_SaveTo1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog folderBrowserDialog1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button Btn_Snapshot;
        private System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox groupBox2;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I did it. Change:

```
var snapShotImage = _snapshotHandler.TakeSnapshot().ToImage();
```

to

```
var snapShotImage = _snapShot.TakeSnapshot().ToImage() as System.Drawing.Image;
```

Comment: the image is taking previous snap can you tell me who to get current iage